# Is Post's Correspondence Problem decidable with fixed word size?

Tags: computability, undecidability, decision-problem

So, it's known that PCP is undecidable even when we fix the number of tiles to $n \geq 7$.

I'm wondering, can anything similar be said for when there is a fixed word length?

To be precise, here's the problem:

> Given fixed $m$ and $n$, with $n \geq 7$, and words
>   $u_1, \ldots u_n$ and  $v_1 \ldots v_n$ such that $|u_i| \leq m$ and $|v_i| \leq m$,
>   is there an index sequence $i_1, \ldots i_k$ such that 
>   $u_{i_1} \cdots u_{i_k} = v_{i_1} \cdots v_{i_k}$.

For what values of $m$, if any, is this known to be undecidable?

Note that this is similar to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/701/decidable-restrictions-of-the-post-correspondence-problem), but none of the 8 linked papers seemed by their titles to answer my question, and I haven't fully read all 8 of them yet.

Comment: There is another parameter, the target alphabet size. This has to be unbounded since otherwise your problem is trivially decidable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For all $m \geq 3$, the problem is undecidable.

Proof by reduction from the word problem of unrestricted grammars:

1. Take an arbitrary formal grammar. W.l.o.g. all left and right sides of rules have length at most $3$.

   This can be seen by translating any grammar into an equivalent TM and then [converting back](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6510/98).
2. [Map the resulting grammar to PCP instances](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Post_correspondence_problem); no tile is longer than the longest left or right side of a rule.

   That is, with step 1, all tiles have length $\geq 3$.

Comment: That is: bound on world length $m$, but no bound on number of words $n$. The question seems to look for bounds on both, but see comment by Yuval. (nevertheless +1)

Comment: @HendrikJan Hm, true, missed that ("fixed $n$"). I wonder how to go about that; maybe via a small universal TM?

Comment: Originally I was looking for fixed $m$ and $n$, but this is still a very interesting result regardless!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, it's really weird if you have fixed $m$ and $n$ since technically then you're dealing with a finite, therefore regular, language. There probably is no algorithm which can generate a description of that language (RE, DFA etc.) since you'd need to solve each PCP instance, but there is a finite number of instances with fixed $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @jmite If you bound $\Sigma$, yes. (As Yuval noted.)